# Backup Windows user's profile

Tags: powershell

I do a lot of PC swaps/replacements for my role. I've decided to write a script to assist with backing up the user's profile and network drives.

I'd like to see how my script stands now. I'm still working to implement more features such as backing up saved wireless networks and printers.

```
#get current user's ID
$userID=$env:UserName

#####################################
### Backup user's saved documents ###
#####################################

$FoldersToCopy = @(
    'Desktop'
    'Downloads'
    'Favorites'
    'Documents'
    'Pictures'
    'Videos'
    'AppData'
    )

$SourceRoot      = "C:\Users\$User"
$DestinationRoot = "$PSScriptRoot\fileBackup\$userID\"

foreach( $Folder in $FoldersToCopy ){
    $Source      = Join-Path -Path $SourceRoot -ChildPath $Folder
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $DestinationRoot -ChildPath $Folder

    Robocopy.exe $Source $Destination 
    }

#####################################
###  Backup user's mapped drives  ###
#####################################

$mappedDrives = @()
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

foreach ($drive in $drives) {
    if ($drive.DisplayRoot) {
        $mappedDrives += Select-Object Name,DisplayRoot -InputObject $drive
    }
}

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $PSScriptRoot\fileBackup\$userID\mappedDrives
$mappedDrives | Export-Csv $PSScriptRoot\fileBackup\$userID\mappedDrives\mappedDrives.csv
```

Comment: Be careful to assume that desktop, documents, etc. will be located at `C:\Users\[Username]\...`. They can be moved. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/878605/getting-all-special-folders-in-net

Comment: @S.Walker Thats a great point. Thank you very much for pointing that out and providing that reference. I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good to me. A few notes:

---

You have a bug here:

```
$userID=$env:UserName

$SourceRoot      = "C:\Users\$User"
```

You are referring to `$User`, which hasn't been set. I always put this at the top of my scripts to catch such bugs:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
```

Why introduce a new variable, by the way? Why not just use it directly?:

```
$SourceRoot      = "C:\Users\$env:UserName"
```

---

This line can be simplified for the sake of readability:

```
$Source      = Join-Path -Path $SourceRoot -ChildPath $Folder
```

To this:

```
$Source      = Join-Path $SourceRoot $Folder
```

---

This code would be cleaner using the pipeline:

```
$mappedDrives = @()

foreach ($drive in $drives) {
    if ($drive.DisplayRoot) {
        $mappedDrives += Select-Object Name,DisplayRoot -InputObject $drive
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
$mappedDrives = $drives | ? $drive.DisplayRoot | Select-Object Name, DisplayRoot
```

(Not tested because I don't have any mapped drives, but I believe it is correct.)

You can format it like this if you like:

```
$mappedDrives = $drives |
    ? $drive.DisplayRoot | 
    Select-Object Name, DisplayRoot
```

---

This comment is misleading:

```
#####################################
###  Backup user's mapped drives  ###
#####################################
```

You aren't backing up the drives. You are recording the drive mappings.

Comment: This is prefect. Thank you very much! I didn't notice that bug at all. I'll have to play around with the pipeline suggestion. I received a few errors when I ran it as displayed above. Everything else makes total sense and I've updated my script accordingly.

Comment: @freeWind, you're welcome. You still need this line, by the way: `$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem`  That might have been a bit unclear.